# SDL2 and measuring the time a key is pressed

Tags: c++, time, key, sdl-2

I have written the follow (typical) code snippet for handling key events in SDL2:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

// Custom key types
typedef enum Keys {
    Back,
    Reset
} KeyType;

// Structure that holds the type and pressed state of custom keys
typedef struct Button {
    KeyType type;
    bool pressed;
} Button;

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    // Variables
    bool quit = false;
    SDL_Event event;

    Button buttons[] = {
        {Back, false},
        {Reset, false}
    };

    // Initialize SDL sub-systems, window, renderer and texture
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_Window * window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL2 Keyboard/Mouse events",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 640, 640, 0);
    SDL_Renderer * renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);

    // Loop while quit not disabled
    while (!quit)
    {
        // Pool events
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            // Filter events
            switch (event.type)
            {
            case SDL_QUIT:  // Window closed
                quit = true;
                break;
            case SDL_KEYDOWN:   // Key pressed
                switch (event.key.keysym.sym)
                {
                case SDLK_ESCAPE:
                    quit = true;
                    break;
                case SDLK_LEFT:
                    buttons[Back].pressed = true;   // Toggle Back button to pressed
                    cout << "Back held" << endl;
                    // TODO Measure elapsed time and artificially toggle the pressed state to false if > 5s
                    break;
                case SDLK_DOWN:
                    buttons[Reset].pressed = true;  // Toggle Reset button to pressed
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case SDL_KEYUP:     // Key released
                switch (event.key.keysym.sym)
                {
                case SDLK_LEFT:
                    if (buttons[Back].pressed) {
                         // TODO Measure elapsed time and print "Back emitted" if less than 5s
                         buttons[Back].pressed = false;  // Toggle Back button to unpressed and emit Back event
                    }
                    break;
                case SDLK_DOWN:
                    buttons[Reset].pressed = false; // Toggle Reset button to unpressed
                    cout << "Reset emitted" << endl;
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case SDL_USEREVENT:
                break;
            }

            SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
            SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
        }
    }

    // Cleanup resources
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    // Stop all SDL sub-systems
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to figure out a way to measure the time between the moment when `buttons[Back].pressed` is set to `true` (even when holding the key down only the exact begin of the "holding" is what I'm interested in) and then to `false`. The "key released" part is easy since this a single event anyway.

I want to distinguish between a **short** (single "key pressed" event received or holding the key for less than let's say 5s) and **long** (more than 5s holding the key down) **strokes** which is basically mapping two actions to the same key based on the time a key is held by the user.

I can't figure out how to do that. Any ideas? I need to handle the time event in two location (imho):

- Given key is released - if elapsed time is less/equal to 5s detect a **short key stroke** else **long key stroke**
- While given key is in being pressed - if the timeout kicks in, the pressed state needs to be artificially toggled to `false` in order to prevent a **short key stroke** to be detected when the user actually releases the key. In this case a **long key stroke** is detected

Comment: [`SDL_GetTicks()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetTicks) or [`SDL_GetPerformanceCounter()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetPerformanceCounter)?

Comment: The problem is not which to use but how exactly. I can also use the `std::chrono` from the standard C++ library, SDL2 timers etc. The problem is how to nail that exact first toggling of the `pressed`.

Comment: @rbaleksandar e.g. add time to your `Button` structure, and filter out repeated press/release events.

Comment: By checking if the elapsed time is == 0 or not? In case == 0, this would mean that this is the initial trigger for the time measurement since once a a short or long stroke is detected that parameter inside the struct will be reset.

Comment: @rbaleksandar I don't think I understand you but yes that way you can get how much time passed after key press.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expanded upon @keltar 's suggestion and it works although not that precise (but in my case it's not required.

I added `elapsedTime` in the `Button` struct to hold the time information and initialized it to `0`:

```
typedef struct Button {
    KeyType type;
    bool pressed;
    uint32_t elapsedTime;
} Button;
```

Whenever the given key is pressed down I check if the `elapsedTime == 0` and if so I call `SDL_GetTicks()`. Upon releasing the key I get the `currentTime` which is just another call of `SDL_GetTicks()` at that point in time. I calculate the difference between `elapsedTime` and `currenTime` and check if a specific time interval has elapsed and then make a decision what function is called.

This solution can be expanded by making the calculation above during every loop iteration and making the exact same check. This makes it possible to check the elapsed time not only upon releasing the given key and it is a more accurate answer to my initial question. However the first solution (without the extra check) works fine. I just had to adapt my scenario a little bit.